# Why does Microsoft not show other browsers' icons?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, icons, tiles

I find the following tiles in my Windows 10 start menu:
[image: Image showing Microsoft browser icons and Firefox working just fine, but Chrome as black and Opera as white.]

Depending on apparently-random factors, the Chrome label is sometimes black-on-black and so totally unrecognizable:
[image]

If I make the tiles smaller (quarter-size), the last two are still just black or white but without any label, so it's much harder to see what they open.

I've tried deleting `%localappdata%\IconCache.db` and deleting
`%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*` and rebooting, but that made no difference.

Edit: I've also done `right-click -> Open File Location` twice (to reach the actual program), inspected the `appname.VisualElementsManifest.xml` file, and verified that the logo files referenced there actually exist.  After one "Open File Location" (viewing the shortcut in Explorer) the icon is displayed with the program name, but this doesn't fix the start menu.

I would have thought Microsoft would've learned not to do this after the browser wars [antitrust case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Microsoft_Corp.), but maybe not.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This isn't any nefarious act on MS' part, and the fact the Mozilla icon works proves that. It gets you no closer to a solution to postulate extra-legal machinations and pontificate on decades-old lawsuits. You're probably going on the right path working on icon caches, but I'd also reinstall the browsers to see if they own icons might be corrupt or missing.

Comment: "Why is this happening?" - It isn't because of anything Microsoft is doing on purpose because my Windows 10 installation has no problem displaying Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Firefox in the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1):

**Right-click** on the shortcuts that are missing icons, select **More**, and then **Open file location**.

Now observe whether the icons are missing for the shorcuts in this folder.

If they are missing here as well you should be able to right-click and open **Properties** for each shortcut, and then choose a new icon for them.

Another option is to simply run a repair install of the browsers.

If both of these fail, personally I'd consider the next easiest thing to be to fully uninstall both browsers, and then reinstall them.

Comment: +1 for your answer, but it didn't fix the problem (see edits).

Comment: Have you reinstalled/repair installed? Have you run the DISM scanhealth and restorehealth commands to check for proper Windows setup?